# Airflow - Persist task state/checkpoint information in a long running Task

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a task that can run for ~10+ hours, say in a for loop.

I want to store **checkpoints** after each loop execution, so that if there is some error in the task or if the worker crashes, the retried task can resume from where it left off by retrieving the checkpoint information specific to that task run.

So, the question is, how and where can I store this check point information?

The task logic is below :-

```
long_running_task:
    seqNo = getStoredCheckpointForTask() 
    do
        if(seqNo == null )        
            seqNo = getFirstSequenceFromSomeSource() //1-2 seconds
        
        doSomething(seqNo);  //3-4 seconds
        seqNo = getNextSequenceFromSomeSource(oldSeq: seqNo) //1-2 seconds

        storeCheckpointForTask (seqNo);

    while sequence != null
```

Answer (score 0):

If your task is running on Airflow workers, you have two options:

- You can use an external storage system as checkpoints store (ex S3):
- Or using Airflow Metadata (Airflow DB) as checkpoints store by saving an xcom

```py
def my_task_func(**context):
    seqNo = context["ti"].xcom_pull(key=f"checkpoint_{context['execution_date']}", default=None)
    while True:
        if not seqNo:
            seqNo = getFirstSequenceFromSomeSource()
        doSomething(seqNo)
        seqNo = getNextSequenceFromSomeSource(seqNo)
        if not seqNo:
            break
        context["ti"].xcom_push(key=f"checkpoint_{context['execution_date']}", seqNo)
```

And if your task is running outside Airflow, the first option is still valid, but the second no, and you will have another options depending on how you run your tasks (volumes for docker, PVC for K8S, ...).

Comment: If the task restarts, is the context still valid? Also, is this context valid only for that specific DAG run ?

Comment: I just updated my answer by adding the execution date to the key name, in this case you will have a different checkpoint per run. So when the task restart, your task will be able to fetch this value from the Metadata, and use it to continue the processing from the last seqNo in the previous retry, and when you start a new run, your task will work with a new checkpoint